# Turning points of an absolute value equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Given the equation
$$\left| x\; -\; c \right|\; +\; \left| x\; +\; c \right|\; -\; \left| y \right|\; -\; \left| \left| x\; -\; c \right|\; -\; \left| y \right| \right|\; = b \text{,} -c, c, b \in \mathbb{R}\text{,}$$
what are it's turning points and how many solutions to that equation is?

---

A little edit:
By turning points I mean a points, at which absolute values change it's sign.

Obviously, those are $-c, c$ for $x$ and $0$ for $y$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out an equals sign, or do you not intend it to be an equation?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins accidentaly.